# Assign and remove items from one category

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

[Assign many items to one category - OneToMany Relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579671/assign-many-items-to-one-category-onetomany-relation)

and

[Symfony form not saving entity with ManyToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30463674/symfony-form-not-saving-entity-with-manytomany-relation)

Based on the two questions above I have an list with many checkboxes for all items. So it does not make any sense to have 2 Routes/Methods: One for assign and another for removing the items. To make it logically correct, assign items and remove items have to be in one method - this method down under is only working for assigning and not for removing one ore more items. In a real application assign and remove items in one step is the only way it makes sense (because of the checkboxes).

```
/**
 * Assign items to category and remove items from the list
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/assign", name="category_assign")
 * @Template("CheckoutItemBundle:Category:assign.html.twig")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param $id
 * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
 */
public function assignAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('CheckoutItemBundle:Category')->find($id);

    if (!$entity)
    {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Category entity.');
    }

    $tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');

    $form = $this->createForm(new CategoryItemType($tokenStorage), $entity, array(
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        $data = $form->getData();
        foreach($data->getItems() as $item)
        {
            $item->setCategory($entity);
            $em->persist($item);
        }

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('category'));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

Form:

```
<?php

namespace Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class CategoryItemType extends AbstractType
{
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        $builder
            ->add('items', 'entity', array(
                'label' => 'Items',
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'CheckoutItemBundle:Item',
                'property' => 'name',
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->where('c.user = :user')
                        ->setParameter('user', $currentUser);
                },
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Category'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'checkout_bundle_itembundle_category_items';
    }
}
```

Entity Category:

```
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Item", mappedBy="category", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    private $items;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $user;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
```

**Here the complete one: http://laravel.io/bin/bEEr5 (It's just to long, to paste it here.)**

Entity Item:

```
class Item

{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="guid")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description = null;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\ItemCharakter", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     **/
    private $itemCharakters;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $category;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Tax", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Items_Taxes")
     */
    private $taxes;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Checkout\Bundle\ItemBundle\Entity\Modifier", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Items_Modifiers")
     */
    private $modifiers;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $created_at
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime $updated_at
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated_at;
```

**the complete entity: http://laravel.io/bin/XyyxB**

### .

First scenario:

```
Assign Items to Category:
[ ] Item 1
[ ] Item 2
```

assign all ====>

```
Assign Items to Category:
[X] Item 1
[X] Item 2
```

Second:

```
Assign Items to Category:
[ ] Item 1  // Remove this item 1, after it was assign
[X] Item 2  // Stay assigned
```

I'm not on the owning side here. I'm using Symfony 2.6.7. In this example it is an OneToMany Relation, but in the future I need it also for ManytoMany Relation.

Any idea, how this is possible for OneToMany and ManyToMany, when I'm not on the owning side? :-)

I also followed this guide for the adding items part: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations - may it help to clarify.

Comment: please show your form and entities.

Comment: How about making your relation bilateral ?

Comment: The relation is bilateral - it is working, when I'm on the owning side (Add Category from select to one item, by editing the item). 

@DerStoffel: Updated question.

Comment: On line 145 -> 152 of your category entity, $items->setCategory($this); should come *before* $this->items[] = $items; - this may or may not be causing your problem, but it's certainly not helping.